# Automatically upload images from desktop app to web app?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, winforms, razor

I'd appreciate if someone could advise me on following.

I've created a `Windows Forms Application` that contains an image gallery. I would like to automatically upload any of the images (by clicking a button) to my web application which is `ASP.NET MVC 4`. The image should appear on my view at once.

I thought to use some web service, that would have methods to upload images from desktop app into database, and then the button click will redirect me to my `asp.net mvc` web page where I display the last uploaded image from db.

What could be the best way to achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's nothing wrong with that approach. In fact, that's pretty common in SOA and it is pretty easy to implement with WCF. One thing to point out

1. Security, can anyone post images your service? Even anonymous users? You should consider applying some security here or else a nasty user can  bring your service down by posting a too many photos. It's not hard to create a multi-threaded console app capable of making countless request to your service per minute

Comment: Oh thanks. Well, the application is corporate, it will be installed inside one company only and the web app will be published on local server. And each user will have own page to post images to. Thanks for your consideration!